# Objective C change pinch gesture view

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming, gesture, pinch

I'm stuck with a problem with pinch gesture. So I have a pinch gesture on an UIImageView which is itself in a collectionView, and when the user starts zooming, I add new, separates ViewController to control the zoom and pan gestures on the image, so I add my UIImageView to the new ViewController's view. The problem is, when I change my UIImageView hierarchy, the pinch gesture attached to it stops working, so the user has to take off his fingers and start pinch again in order to zoom the image. So basically, I am searching solutions to one off these:
 1. Make pinch gesture work right when changing gesture.view hierarchy
 OR
 2. Make pinch gesture work right when changing gesture.view. So another way is to add a new view to the new ViewController and attach gesture to that view. But it still resets the gesture touches and you need to start it again.

If anyone has any suggestions, please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. You just need to set userinteraction of vc's view to NO. Works like a charm.